# MySQL 2 Million Rows, longtext and varchar indexes

Tags: mysql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'm trying to find a solution for this, with no success.

I have a table with ~2M rows, and I need to do a WHERE with 3 expressions using OR.

```
name LIKE '%PARAM%' OR text1 LIKE '%PARAM%' OR text2 LIKE '%PARAM%' ORDER BY views DESC
```

name is a varchar

text1 and text2 are longtext (~6000 characters each)

```
text1 and text2 are indexed FULLTEXT
name is indexed BTREE, views too.
```

The table is MyISAM, it don't have many updates, but many selects;

The query takes ~12sec to complete.

Sorry if this question arleady exists, but I could not found this.

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each run of this query will scan the whole table for two reasons:

- The index on `name` will not be used as the value starts with a wild char `%`
- You are not using the proper functions that utilize the `fulltext` index on the other two fields.

Proposed solution:

- add a `fulltext` index on `name` field
- Use the proper functions to search. in this case, it is `match` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Notice: Depending on your version of MySQL, using `OR` to combine conditions could be a performance hit. It is not the case in 5.6 +